# List of repeating integers

Tags: python, algorithm, list

What is the most pythonic way to create a list of given size `N= l*k` where `l` is the number of different symbols (integers for simplicity) and `k` is the subsequence length like this:

`N=12`, `l=4`, `k=3`

```
[ 0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3 ]
```

or this for example `N=15` `l=3`, `k=5`:

```
[ 0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2 ]
```

this function should be called very often so speed is desirable.

Comment: a viable option should be

` [ [ y for x in range(0,k) ] for y in range(0,l) ] ` but the list is a list of lists

Comment: so remove the inner brackets. but zhangxaochen answered that already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `numpy` you can do this:

```
In [23]: import numpy as np

In [26]: a=np.arange(3).repeat(5)

In [27]: a
Out[27]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

or python builtin:

```
In [29]: [l for l in range(3) for k in range(5)]
Out[29]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: fast and efficient, I was very close to solution in fact :P

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> l=3
>>> k=5
>>> [e for i in range(l) for e in [i]*k]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

I like this **lazy** version (it returns an iterator, not a list, and you can generate values out of it when you want).

```
l, k = 3, 5
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(i, k) for i in xrange(l))
```

It outputs this:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(i, k) for i in xrange(l)))
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps with [itertools.repeat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) and [itertools.chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)?

```
>>> from itertools.import repeat, chain
>>> k = 3
>>> l = 4
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(list(repeat(x, k)) for x in xrange(l))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: That's not exactly they way the OP wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sum([[x]*3 for x in xrange(4)], [])
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

Putting it into a function:

```
def combine(l, k):
   return sum([[x]*k for x in xrange(l)], [])
```

Comment: That's not exactly they way the OP wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

l = 3
k = 5

print(list(itertools.chain(*[[i] * k for i in range(l)])))

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```